# terminal -e with multiple commands

Tags: bash, terminal

I have an Arch Linux machine with Openbox, and I want to run an update on my autostart script (bash) - so I added the following command to my autostart: `rxvt -e sudo pacman -Syu &` (i.e. open `rxvt` terminal and run the standard update command for Archlinux's package manager, `pacman`).

However, sometimes the database is locked by another `pacman` process, and then the command fails and just closes `rxvt` without doing anything - so I wanted to remove the lock first by using `rxvt -e  sudo rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck && sudo pacman -Syu &` (remove the lock on pacman and then update). This doesn't work as actually only the first command is executed in the `rxvt` instance.

Is there any way to get it right (running two commands on a terminal opened with a `-e` flag)? I know I could open two separate terminals, each executing one command, but that would be really messy in my opinion. Alternatively, if there's another simpler way to make sure the lock isn't there, it's also okay by me (although I prefer it on the same terminal so I can see the output of the `rm` clearly)

Comment: Or maybe only run pacman if the lock file does NOT exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes to make this a single command:

```
rxvt -e  "sudo rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck && sudo pacman -Syu" &
```

Some terminals need that to be wrapped in a shell command, e.g.,

```
rxvt -e sh -c "sudo rm -f /var/lib/pacman/db.lck && sudo pacman -Syu" &
```

The `-f` flag ignores the file if it's not there and avoids an error

Comment: Thanks, I did try the first command before asking, but only the second did the trick. Only I had to change it to `rm -f` in case the file isn't there (so it doesn't throw me out)